# Import all files in a table, move existing records into previous and archive

Tags: sql-server

I have a table containing about a dozen tables and their corresponding text files, which are imported each week. The table WEEKLYFILES has fields TABLENAME and FILENAME.

Here's what I need to do...

Go through the table of tablenames and for each table, take the existing table, say, "MYSTUFF" and

1) Move the data in MYSTUFF_previous into MYSTUFF_archive

2) Move the data in MYSTUFF into MYSTUFF_previous

3) Import the new data in text file C:\mystuff.txt into MYSTUFF

Somehow I have to do something like:

```
SELECT @TABLENAME = TABLENAME, @FILENAME = FILENAME FROM WEEKLYFILES
```

and then for each record, do something like

```
INSERT INTO @TABLENAME_archive SELECT * FROM @TABLENAME_previous
```

-- To copy existing data to Previous:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE @TABLENAME_previous; 

INSERT INTO @TABLENAME_previous SELECT * FROM @TABLENAME
```

then to load new text file use Bulk Insert to load current table after clearing it

```
TRUNCATE TABLE @TABLENAME; 

BULK INSERT @TABLENAME FROM @FILENAME WITH 
 ( 
    FIELDTERMINATOR =',', 
     ROWTERMINATOR ='\n' 
);
```